# Initializing an NOR SR latch

Tags: circuit-design

We know for a fact that the initial state of a NOR SR latch is indeterminate until either the SET or RESET pin receives a digital HIGH. I am using an SR latch in my circuit, and I want to initialize the latch such that the SET pin will receive a digital HIGH pulse upon powering up the circuit.

Will a monostable multivibrator be able to do the job, or are there simpler solutions or methods that I do not know of?

[image: The circuit in question]

Comment: `methods that I do not know of` ... there is no way to accurately guess about your knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create a pulse of approx. 10 us, then disconnect itself.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0UMdn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How do you reduce the size of a CircuitLab schematic after it has been created and inserted?

Comment: stretch the schematic out horizontally. The system sets the size of the schematic to be the width of SE's text. You could put something useless at the far right if you want.

Comment: Really - ?  There isn't a better, more conteolled way than that?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to generate a reset pulse for initializing logic is to use a supervisory chip designed for the purpose. They will generate a "bulletproof" pulse of guaranteed minimum duration for any any excursion of the supply voltage outside of a specific range, with guaranteed limits. The only thing you have to do, other than specify the chip, is to guarantee the supply voltage cannot change too quickly (so that a very short drop would be faster than the reset chip could react but it would corrupt the state of the latch).

Any simple RC reset can be fooled by blips in the supply and similar startup or upsets that are not "clean" reset from zero after a long delay. It is the use of sub-standard reset circuit that is responsible for a lot of misbehavior of consumer electronic devices.
A proper reset chip includes an accurate and well-specified voltage reference and comparator that works down to a very low supply voltage, as well as a timer.

You can search for various options, one popular choice is the [ADM80x](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM803_809_810.pdf) series, originally developed by Analog Devices.

[image]

They tend to cost 5-10 cents in moderate quantity, which may seem a bit extravagant, but usually it's worth it for non-battery-powered devices.

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest method is to put little capacity (like 47p) to one of SR flop pin what couses an imbalance during powering up. The disadvantage of it is the capacity will damage the edges during normal oparation.

A better solution is to use a RC delay:

[image]

After C1 is charged to 4v3 the 5v signal flowing from D2 diode to S pin dissapear. The disadvantage is when power-up is too slow the R3C1 time constant is ineffective. However the circuit should still work becouse at 4v3 when D2 signal is going to dissapear the SR is working already so it should be properly initialized to Set state.